# Java+MySQL+unixsocket

Tags: unix-socket, java, mysql

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, может кто сталкивался, поддерживает ли стандартный Connector/J (com.mysql.jdbc.Driver) unix-socket в качестве среды передачи данных и как формируется URL для подключение в таком случае.

В ТСР-режиме все работает.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [junixsocket](http://code.google.com/p/junixsocket/wiki/ConnectingToMySQL).